# Jackson infinite recursion when converting to json

Tags: java, json, jsf, serialization, jackson

When trying to convert a custom object `Tag` which has the below structure to json, it gives me the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion` because of `getValueArray()` function

```
public class Tag {
    private String vr;
    @JsonProperty("Value")
    private JsonNode Value;

    //getters and setters

    public org.primefaces.model.TreeNode getValueArray() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("enter check");
        TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode();
        constructTree(Value, 1, root);
        return root;
    }
}
```

I have a getter for `Value` that returns String instead of JsonNode (for specific reason), and I have this `getValueArray` that causes the problem, `Jackson` calls this function when converting to json instead of using `getValue` (I know that as `enter check` are printed to console), actually when I remove this function it works, for some reason it calls this function and uses the returned `TreeNode` in it's conversion, I thought the problem might be that it gets confused with `Jackson treeNode`, so I returned `org.primefaces.model.TreeNode` to let it recognizes that this is `primefaces TreeNode` not `Jackson TreeNode`, I don't even know why it calls this function, and how to fix this.

the error said

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode["parent"]->org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode["children"]->org.primefaces.model.TreeNodeChildren[0]->org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode["parent"]................. and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around that works fine, as the problem is that Jackson uses this function `getValueArray()` as a getter in the serialization, because of it's name `get something`, I used

```
@JsonGetter("valueArray")
public JsonNode serializeValue()
{
    return Value;
}
```

`@JsonGetter("valueArray")` lets me force Jackson to use the above function as getter for the non exist property `valueArray` which return the Value, now jackson will no longer uses `getValueArray()` function as getter.